# Freehub movement on Reynolds hub--is this OK?

Tags: freehub

The freehub on my Reynolds wheel moves a bit horizontally when off the bike.  Is there a problem with it, or is it working as designed?

Comment: That doesn't look right - it would screw up gear changes.  When you have the cassette and lockring on does the hub movement stop/reduce ?

Comment: It still moves with cassette and lockring on, but doesn't seem to affect shifting.  I only took the cassette off because I wanted to test out another wheel (to make sure I could use it as a spare).  I don't think it moves once it is fitted on the bike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's going on in that video is either a slip fit endcap has partially slid off, or a threaded one is loose. If they're slip fit than of course it will all be fine once the wheel is back on the bike. If threaded, they should be re-tightened.

Comment: Thanks so much Nathan--obviously I know next to nothing about hubs, but you gave me the right terms to search for--it's threaded and just needs to be tightened.